# Google+ OAuth API - error 400

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus

I'm having a bit of a problem with the Google+ authentication and I can't seem to get my head around it.

I'm running a page on a WAMP server on my local machine. The website is being hosted on localhost:80

I setup the OAuth credentials as follows:

```
REDIRECT URIS  
http://localhost:80/oauth2callback

JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS 
http://localhost:80
```

So the callback and JS origin are both tuned to localhost:80 (as far as I'm aware).

However, when I use the Google+ signin button, I click on my Google account, but then am greeted with the following error message.

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: origin_mismatch

Request Details
=
from_login=1

e=3100077

scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

redirect_uri=postmessage

state=886354831|0.2093651692

origin=http://localhost

as=6ab1e337782cd5f6

pli=1

request_visible_actions=http://schema.org/AddAction

hl=en

response_type=code token id_token gsession

cookie_policy=single_host_origin

proxy=oauth2relay1316100299

include_granted_scopes=true

client_id=/blanked this part for security/-jsaproji1sk0u1b8kjlh3m3n4i232m4b.apps.googleusercontent.com

authuser=0
That’s all we know.
```

Which outlines that the error is due to origin_mismatch. I've tried setting the OAuth origin&redirect credentials to localhost and localhost:80 respectively, but both give an error 400

Could someone with a bit more experience give me a hand? I'm still quite new to this

Thanks in advance, 
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the javascript origins also to: `http://localhost` not just `http://localhost:80`?

The origins must be an *exact* match, and in your query it doesn't contain the port number as part of the origin.

You can add multiple origins by adding one per line.
- Dragonfire